# Kernel panic when running qemu with -curses option?

Tags: debian, qemu

I have a raw qemu disk image of Debian 10 ("buster") with no desktop environment, and I'm trying to run it in the terminal of my host machine (also Debian 10) with the `-curses` flag. If I run `qemu-system-x86_64` with just the `-curses` flag, I just get a blank screen, so following [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/254983/49592) I added the `-vga std` option. Unfortunately, that gives me a kernel panic in the console, and I never reach the login screen of the guest. The output looks like this:

```
[    3.021788]  xwrite+0x29/0x5a
[    3.021845]  do_copy+0x9b/0xc8
[    3.021878]  write_buffer+0x27/0x37
[    3.021912]  flush_buffer+0x34/0x8b
[    3.021947]  __gunzip+0x26e/0x315
[    3.021982]  ? bunzip2+0x397/0x397
[    3.022016]  ? initrd_load+0x5e/0x5e
[    3.022048]  ? __gunzip+0x315/0x315
[    3.022080]  gunzip+0xe/0x11
[    3.022112]  ? initrd_load+0x5e/0x5e
[    3.022143]  unpack_to_rootfs+0x182/0x2c6
[    3.022177]  ? initrd_load+0x5e/0x5e
[    3.022210]  ? unpack_to_rootfs+0x2c6/0x2c6
[    3.022243]  ? do_early_param+0x8e/0x8e
[    3.022275]  populate_rootfs+0x59/0x106
[    3.022311]  do_one_initcall+0x46/0x1c3
[    3.022350]  ? do_early_param+0x8e/0x8e
[    3.022382]  kernel_init_freeable+0x189/0x218
[    3.022419]  ? rest_init+0xaa/0xaa
[    3.022453]  kernel_init+0xa/0x10d
[    3.022487]  ret_from_fork+0x35/0x40
[    3.023243] ---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: System is deadlocked on memo
ry
[    3.023243]  ]---
```

I'm using QEMU emulator version 3.1.0 (Debian 1:3.1+dfsg-8+deb10u3). My terminal is [st](http://st.suckless.org/) 0.8.2 and my desktop environment/window manager is dwm, if those details are relevant. I get the same kernel panic if I use xterm, though.

I'm booting the image with this qemu command:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -curses -vga std -m 1024 -drive format=raw,file=disk.img
```

I've tried other various combinations of qemu flags from [this question](https://serverfault.com/a/677232), but they either don't exist for my version of qemu (e.g. the `-noframe` option), throw other errors (e.g. `-append` requires a `-kernel` option), or just give me a blank screen (`-curses` by itself).

The whole point of this is to avoid launching a VNC viewer to access a guest that is command line only anyway.

Comment: If you run linux with `qemu -curses`, just give it the `nomodeset` (and `systemd.unit=multi-user.target`) options on the _kernel_ command line (I don't think that using `-append ...` works if you're using any kind of boot manager in the guest). Otherwise sooner or later you'll be left with with a black screen with `graphics mode` written in the middle. I'm sorry I can't help you further, as I'm using a (heavily modified) current version of qemu, not that from the distro. I'm also using `-vga virtio`, but I don't know if that works with your older version.

Comment: Thanks for the help. This may be a stupid question, but what do you mean by the "*kernel* command line"? Those aren't options that I pass directly to the `qemu-system-x86_64` command? I can't even get into a boot menu in qemu so I can't (for example) edit boot commands in grub.

Comment: A boot loader like `grub` can pass arguments to the linux kernel. `qemu` knows how to do that directly, if you're using `-kernel ... -append ..`, but that doesn't work with disk images which use a bootloader. Eg. if your image is using `grub`, you can modify them by pressing `e` in the boot screen, adding them after the `linux` entry, and then pressing Ctrl-X to boot through. You can add permanent kernel command options inside the guest by modifying `/etc/default/grub` and running `grub-update`. All that is no different from a real machine.

Comment: @mosvy Perfect! I added `nomodeset systemd.unit=multi-user.target` to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet nomodeset systemd.unit=multi-user.target"` line in `/etc/default/grub`, ran `update-grub`, and now the `qemu-system-x86_64` command in my question works perfectly! Plus I can get easily get that to work with my [preseed file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/556413/49592). I'm happy to summarize this and put it into a community wiki answer, unless you want to. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [mosvy](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/308316/mosvy)'s comments, I added the `nomodeset systemd.unit=multi-user.target` options to the kernel command line, and then qemu booted everything correctly. Since I'm setting up these bootable iso images with a [preseed file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/556414/49592), I added this line to `preseed.cfg`:

```
d-i debian-installer/add-kernel-opts string nomodeset systemd.unit=multi-user.target
```